# Getting size of LPTSTR or CHAR* containing hex values

Tags: c, windows, string, winapi, sizeof

I'm trying to get the size of an LPTSTR variable and a CONST CHAR variable using the below code, but I'm not able to get the proper size.

I'm supposed to get 20, but instead I'm getting 0 for the const char* variable and 4 for the LPTSTR variable.

```
const char *var1 =  "\x00\x00\x00\x00"
                    "\x00\x00\x00\x00"
                    "\x02\x00\x00\x00"
                    "\x5B\xE0\x5B\xE0"
                    "\x00\x00\x00\x00";

LPTSTR var2 =       "\x00\x00\x00\x00"
                    "\x00\x00\x00\x00"
                    "\x02\x00\x00\x00"
                    "\x5B\xE0\x5B\xE0"
                    "\x00\x00\x00\x00";

printf("%d",  sizeof(var1));  // this outputs 0
printf("%d",  sizeof(var2));  // this outputs 4
```

I need to get the size of the value to insert it into the Windows Registry as binary data (`REG_BINARY`) using the following function:

```
lRes = RegSetValueEx(hMykey, "Scancode Map", 0, REG_BINARY, (LPBYTE) var2, sizeof(var2));
```

Comment: How are you getting 0 for the first one ? Doesn't seem right.

Comment: Sorry i'm getting 4 for sizeof(var1)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The type of `var1` is `const char*`, and the size of `var2` is `LPTSTR` (which is your case is an alias to `char*`).  `sizeof var1` is equivalent to `sizeof (const char*)`, not the size of the character array it's pointing to.  On your platform, `sizeof (char*)` is 4 bytes.

You instead could do:

```
const char var1[] = { 0x00, 0x00, ..., 0x00 };
```

And then `sizeof var1` would be equivalent to `sizeof (const char[20])`, which is what you want.

Comment: Yes, im able to get the size now. Thank you.

Comment: But how to initialize const char var1[] with cont char* value, which i'm getting through the function parameter?

Comment: @hardyRocks: If you're getting it through a function parameter, the caller will need to pass along the size.

Answer (score 0):

you need to do

```
const char var1[20] =  "\x00\x00\x00\x00"
                "\x00\x00\x00\x00"
                "\x02\x00\x00\x00"
                "\x5B\xE0\x5B\xE0"
                "\x00\x00\x00\x00";
```

Comment: Yeah, but the value will be dynamic, it may vary.

Comment: Well you can do what @jamesdlin is suggesting. But if the values will be dynamic, perhaps you should allocate your memory dynamically as well.

Comment: @hardyRocks: If the array size is dynamic, then you need to allocate memory dynamically and will need to keep track of the size yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Alternative:

```
#define STR "\x00\x00\x00\x00" \
            "\x00\x00\x00\x00" \
            "\x02\x00\x00\x00" \
            "\x5B\xE0\x5B\xE0" \
            "\x00\x00\x00\x00"
const char * var1 = STR;

printf("%d\n", sizeof(STR)-1);
```

Not sure what is the purpose of these variables, but you can also do

lRes = RegSetValueEx(hMykey, "Scancode Map", 0, REG_BINARY, (LPBYTE) STR, sizeof(STR)-1);

directly.

Comment: The value will be dynamic, in fact it will be sent thru a function's parameter multiple time with different values everytime. So i can't define the value. The function will call RegSetValueEx function with the value passed and size of the value.

Comment: If that is the case, you need to send the size as an extra argument or embed the size as part of the data. Because all you have is a pointer to the data, you cannot deduce the "size" of the data you point to from the pointer.

Comment: According to info from MS.

typedef CHAR *LPSTR;

LPSTR   A pointer to a null-terminated string of 8-bit Windows (ANSI) characters.
        For more information, see Character Sets Used By Fonts.

LPTSTR  An LPWSTR if UNICODE is defined, an LPSTR otherwise.

#ifdef UNICODE
 typedef LPWSTR LPTSTR;
#else
 typedef LPSTR LPTSTR;
#endif

So these strings are suppose to be null terminated, that is the data itself
does not contain binary 0s, but the terminating bytes is 0. But in the example
you gave, you embed binary 0s?